# Add an image on top of existing one with ImageMagick command line

Tags: imagemagick

i would like to add a series of images to existing one, using imagemagick command line.

- i have this image: http://tinypic.com/r/313386r/6 and
- i would like to add this to this one: http://tinypic.com/r/k0jbqs/6
- to get more or less this effect: http://tinypic.com/r/wtja74/6 .

as you see, this is not only adding an image. i found http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/ where i could see some examples, but what i need is to fill each 'block'.

i have exact position where each block starts and ends, also i have a scale parameter to scale it down.

i think i could use

```
composite -geometry +31+105  toadd.gif source.gif  newfile.jpg
```

but this is only one image added, and i need it scaled down.

i was wondering if i can create some kind of rectangles and fill them with my image.

any idea how it can be solved?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Convert would be better as you can keep adding images with composite or layers.

Here is a very rough example and I would probably start off with a longer section of wall so you could crop it when resizing. There is still going to be quite a bit of user input to fix the locations as I pressume you do not always have the same amount of walls at the same length.
I would write some code to input details into a form as it would be easier than altering the code each time.

```
convert k0jbqs.jpg \
   ( 313386r.png -thumbnail x25 ) -gravity west   -geometry  +0+30 -composite \
   ( 313386r.png -thumbnail x25 ) -gravity center -geometry +80+30 -composite \
   ( 313386r.png -thumbnail x25 ) -gravity east   -geometry  +0+30 -composite \
   output.png
```

You would need to take the line breaks out I just added those to make the code readable.

NOTES: Thumbnail resizes the brick image; you can forget the gravity and just use -geometry and the numbers are the positions from the top left corner and -composite puts the new image over the previous image.

Comment: could you tell me what does `-thumbnail` do? and also why in first block there is `-gravity west` in second `-gravity center` and in third `-gravity east` ? in my images i will have exact position of each block (there are maximum 4 blocks), and for what is `composite`?

Comment: I will add some notes to the answer.

Comment: if width of one of the block is bigger than my brick image, how do repeat it horizontaly and crop it when the block finishes?

Comment: As I said I would start with a longer block in the first place as it is easy to crop. Something like this should work ( 313386r.png -thumbnail x25 -crop 100x25+0+0) 100 = block width 25 = block height +0+0 = no offset in the x or y directions.